# Is there a way to check for a right mouse button click in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am building a version of Risk in JavaFX with FXML for school. Now we want to be able to right click a button to decrease the amount of troops in a country and left click it to increase the amount. The left click was pretty self explanatory as it is just an onAction, but how would we check for a right click on a button, through FXML?

```
<Button id="ontario" fx:id="ontario" layoutX="356.0" layoutY="145.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#countryPressed" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" styleClass="CountryButton" stylesheets="@style.css" 
    <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="16.0" />
    </font>
</Button>
```

Comment: work through a tutorial on how to use fxml and/or read the fxml spec (hint: look at the onXX methods :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To react to a right mouse button click in javaFX, you would use the `onMouseClicked` event handler, and in the `MouseEvent`, check for which button was pressed using method `getButton`, which will return a `MouseButton` with value `MIDDLE`, `PRIMARY`, or `SECONDARY`

Controller code:

```java
  @FXML
  public void buttonClicked(MouseEvent event) {
      switch (event.getButton()) {
      case PRIMARY: //Left button
          //Do something
          break;
      case SECONDARY: //Right button
          //Do something else
          break;
      default:
          //Ignore
          break;
      }
  }
```

FXML:

```xml
<Button fx:id="ontario" onMouseClicked="#buttonClicked">
```

Comment: My bad. Too eager to respond. Corrected.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I figured it out myself already, but this is pretty close to what I have now.